# JSONStore Android app on x86_64 emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, jsonstore, ibm-mobilefirst

I've built a MobileFirst 6.3 app that uses JSONStore and tried to run it on the x86_64 Android emulator. I got

```
02-15 13:11:54.600: D/com.worklight.nativeandroid.common.WLUtils(2081):
 WLUtils.loadLib in WLUtils.java:539 :: 
 Extracting zip file: featurelibs/armeabi/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
02-15 13:11:54.800: D/com.worklight.nativeandroid.common.WLUtils(2081):
 WLUtils.loadLib in WLUtils.java:549 :: 
 Loading library using System.load: /data/data/com.OfflineAuthSample/files/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
02-15 13:11:54.810: E/art(2081): dlopen("/data/data/com.OfflineAuthSample/files/libcrypto.so.1.0.0", RTLD_LAZY) 
 failed: dlopen failed: "/data/data/com.OfflineAuthSample/files/libcrypto.so.1.0.0" 
 has unexpected e_machine: 40
02-15 13:11:54.890: E/wl.jsonstore(2081): 
{"src":"initCollection",
 "err":-11,
 "msg":"OPERATION_FAILED_ON_SPECIFIC_DOCUMENT",
 "col":"userCredentials",
 "usr":"hola",
 "doc":"dlopen failed: \"/data/data/com.OfflineAuthSample/files/libcrypto.so.1.0.0\" has unexpected e_machine: 40",
 "res":{}}
```

`e_machine: 40` [seems to mean `EM_ARM`](http://www.sco.com/developers/gabi/2000-07-17/ch4.eheader.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using any other emulator (x86 or ARM) did the trick**

MobileFirst Studio 6.3 does not seem to include native libraries for the 64 bits intel emulator

```
projName\apps\appName\android\native\libs>tree /f
C:.
|   ...
│
├───armeabi
│       ...
│
├───armeabi-v7a
│       ...
│
├───mips
│       ...
│
└───x86
        ...
```